# SecurityException crash opening link in external browser, when MX Player is installed

Tags: android, android-intent

Steps to reproduce:

- Disable or uninstall all browsers on the device
- Install [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad)
- Launch MX Player and accept any popups
- Open a link from your app as follows (assume the code is in an Activity):

```
val url = "https://mylink.com"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
val resolveInfo = context.packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0)
if (resolveInfo != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
} else {
    // error handling because no browser is installed
}
```

My app crashes with:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://mylink.com.... cmp=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ActivityWebBrowser } from ProcessRecord{64f9702 20760:com.myapp/u0a65} (pid=20760, uid=10065) not exported from uid 10139
       at android.os.Parcel.createException + 1966(Parcel.java:1966)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1934(Parcel.java:1934)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1884(Parcel.java:1884)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity + 3618(IActivityManager.java:3618)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity + 1673(Instrumentation.java:1673)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult + 4689(Activity.java:4689)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult + 767(FragmentActivity.java:767)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult + 4647(Activity.java:4647)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult + 754(FragmentActivity.java:754)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity + 5008(Activity.java:5008)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity + 4976(Activity.java:4976)
       at com.myapp.MyActivity.someFunction
```

I only see this issue if all browsers are uninstalled/disabled. It appears that MX Player installs itself as a browser in this situation, but can't handle opening links from my app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the Activity to view the URL is resolved and exported with something like this:

```
private fun openUrl(url: String?) {
    if (url == null) return
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    activity?.let {
        val activityInfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(it.packageManager, intent.flags)
        if (activityInfo != null && activityInfo.exported) {
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(it, intent, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is an implicit intent, so it does not specify the app component to start, somehow only an app that can start is  MX Player, and that app, actual the `com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ActivityWebBrowser` do not expose to outside, that why an error occurred

To cover this case, I think we should handle the case no browser installed by the way open a Webview, inside the app

```
try {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(your_link));
    startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e | SecurityException e) {
    // open a Webview
}
```